3 правила за одну переадресацию
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\..+ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

Есть ли какой толковый сервис, убедится в том, что 2 правила работают.

Первый это перенаправление с www
Второй с протокола http

Должно работает, либо оба правила совпадают, либо одно из двух. Через браузер какое то мучение...
И хотелось бы увидеть 3 правило, это убрать слеш с конца url...
До этого вовсе было, 3 отдельных правила. И если все это в url есть, сперва переадресовываем убирая слеш с конца, затем переадресовываем с www и третья переадресация это с протокола.
Жесть, как добавить третье правило, убрать слеш и все это сделать за счет 1 переадресации...

Зачем убирать слеш в конце?

url красивей, читабельней
